# Can I remove Important marker from individual Outlook.com emails?

Tags: outlook.com

I am using Outlook.com and created a rule to mark emails from my manager as Important. Is there a way to remove the Importance marker once I have read the message? All of the solutions I've seen online are for the Windows desktop app, not the web app.